Fetching Supabase data with Dart (Flutter)
I'm using Supabase for data storage in my store application, which I'm developing with Dart (Flutter). In my database, I have two tables named product and product_image, where the product_image table has a many-to-one relationship with the product table. I want to retrieve the product information in the code, and this product requires images, which might include multiple images. My problem is that I don't know how to fetch these products. I'm a junior developer and a bit confused, so please guide me.
ProductImage:
class ProductImage {
  final int id;
  final DateTime createAt;
  final int productId;
  final String imageUrl;
  final int displayOrder;

  ProductImage({
    required this.id,
    required this.createAt,
    required this.productId,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.displayOrder,
  });

  ProductImage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'],
        createAt = DateTime.parse(json['created_at']),
        productId = json['product_id'],
        imageUrl = json['image'],
        displayOrder = json['display_order'];
}

Product
class ProductSup {
  final int id;
  final DateTime createAt;
  final String title;
  final int price;
  final int? previousPrice;
  final List<int> productImage;

  ProductSup(
      {required this.id,
      required this.createAt,
      required this.title,
      required this.price,
      required this.previousPrice,
      required this.productImage});

  ProductSup.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'],
        createAt = DateTime.parse(json['created_at']),
        title = json['title'],
        price = json['price'],
        previousPrice = json['previous_price'],
        productImage = [];
}

product table:

product_image:


Your query should look something like this ->
// Have the [supabse] client prepared first!
final data = await supabase.from('product').select('id, title, price, product_image(id, image, display_order)').eq('id', '**YOUR_PRODUCT_ID**');

For more information, follow up this docs:

One to may relationships in Supabase.
Flutter docs for Supabase.

